# What is the maximum value of $\text{dim ker }A$, where $A$ is $n\times m$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

True or false: "If $A$ is an $n\times m$ matrix, then $\text{dim ker }A\leq n$"

My gut intuitively tells me "**no**"$\,\Rightarrow$ if $m>n$, $\text{dim ker }A\leq m$. I can't think of a simple, concise proof to show this though.

What would be a sufficient proof here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement is false.

Consider the linear map $T:\mathbb{R^3}\to \mathbb{R}$ by $T(x,y,z)=z.$ Then $\dim ker(T) =2 >1$.

Comment: I completely agree with your logic, but what would the matrix $A:T(\vec{x})=A\vec{x}$ look like in this specific case?

Comment: The matrix will be  the $1\times 3$ matrix $\begin{bmatrix}0 &  0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: the dimension of the kernel of $A$ is the dimension of the space that gets mapped to zero.  What happens if $A$ is the zero matrix?  Think about what vectors you are mapping to zero $Ax$ where $x$ has dimension $m\times 1$...

Comment: $T\,(\vec{x})=\vec{0}\,\forall\,\vec{x}\in\mathbb{R}^m$? The fact that $A$ is not necessarily square has me confused.

Comment: It doesn't matter if $A$ is square or not.  It maps vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{m}$ to vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.  The kernel is a subspace of the domain (the from side in the map).